# R - Correct plot of Calendar Spread

Tags: r, plot, calendar

I want to plot the payoff of a calendar spread using R.
I know the values of the legs that together forms the calendar spread.

```
sell_put <- c('-43.66', '-41.66',   '-39.66',   '-37.66',   '-35.66',   '-33.66',   '-31.66',   '-29.66',   '-27.66',   '-25.66',   '-23.66',   '-21.66',   '-19.66',   '-17.66',   '-15.66',   '-13.66',   '-11.66',   '-9.66',    '-7.66',    '-5.66',    '-3.66',    '-1.66',    '0.34', '2.34', '4.34', '6.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34', '8.34')

buy_put <- c('38.72',   '36.72',    '34.72',    '32.72',    '30.72',    '28.72',    '26.72',    '24.72',    '22.72',    '20.72',    '18.72',    '16.72',    '14.72',    '12.72',    '10.72',    '8.72', '6.72', '4.72', '2.72', '0.72', '-1.28',    '-3.28',    '-5.28',    '-7.28',    '-9.28',    '-11.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28',   '-13.28')
```

When I plot the sell_put leg

```
plot(sell_put)
```

I obtain exactly the payoff I expected.
Same for the buy_put leg.

```
plot(buy_put)
```

Now, since I want to plot the payoff of a calendar spread, I sum the two vectors and plot the result, and that's where strange things happened.

```
plot(as.numeric(buy_put)+as.numeric(sell_put)).
```

The result is a flat line, and it's not what I expected (something like a cusp).
The values I provide for the example are calculated from the BS formula, and it works well for every other combination of payoff (vertical spread and so on).

What am I doing wrong in plot the calendar spread payoff?

Comment: All you've really given us is two vectors that always add up to -4.94, and your problem seems to be that they always add up to -4.94. I don't know much about finance, but I find it hard to imagine an answer that does much with what you've provided to go on. Maybe you could show us how you calculated / derived the sell and buy puts?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the system is assuming you have same expiration for both options. I came across this thread whilst searching for the same answer. I hope this info at least put you back on track. I am still searching on how to plot calendar spreads.